# Starting Opc Ua Server from public access to ServerManager Class throws NullPointerException

Tags: c#, server, opc, opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

I tried to start an OPC UA Server this way: http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkdotnet/2.1.0/html/L3ServerTutGSLess01.html

```
ApplicationLicenseManager.AddProcessLicenses(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "License.lic");
MyServerManager server = new MyServerManager();
ApplicationInstance.Default.Start(server, null, server); //Start the server
```

> At `ApplicationInstance.Default.Start(server, null, server)"`
>   following Error Appears:   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an object instance. at
>   UnifiedAutomation.UaServer.ServerSettings..ctor ( ApplicationInstance
>   application ) at
>   UnifiedAutomation.UaServer.ServerManager.OnServerStarting (
>   ApplicationInstance application ) at
>   UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ServerBase.Start ( ApplicationInstance
>   application ) at UnifiedAutomation.UaServer.ServerManager.Start (
>   ApplicationInstance application ) at
>   UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ApplicationInstance.Start ( ServerBase server
>   , WaitCallback callback , Object userData ) at
>   VeitsServer.TapakoServerStarter.StartAkomiServer ( IDevice
>   testDeviceToLink ) in TapakoServerStarter.cs : line . 39 at
>   Implementationstests.OpcUaServerTest.ServerShouldRun ( ) in
>   OpcUaServerTest.cs : line 44

**The same code works fine, if it's started internal from `Main()`. But as soon as i try to call the OpcUaServerStarter over an external Project in the same Project Map (for example a Test Project) the NullReferenceException appears.**

Maybe the Project has to be compiled as a .dll or I have to add some references? Or it has some reason, that the visibility of `MyServerManager`is `internal`at the OPC-UA Website.

The Debug Session before the Exception looks this way:
[image]

`MyServerManager` Class (only critical difference to the working `MyServerManager` may be the `public` encapsulation):

```
 public class MyServerManager : ServerManager
{

    private NodeManager _nodeManager;
    private ObjectModel _objectModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Method is called (from SDK) when NodeManager starts up.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootNodeManager"></param>
    protected override void OnRootNodeManagerStarted(RootNodeManager rootNodeManager)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Node Manager.");

        _nodeManager = new NodeManager(this);
        _nodeManager.Startup();

        _objectModel = new ObjectModel(_nodeManager);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an internal model of the given device and automatically creates nodes and callbacks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="device">AKOMI Device that will be shown on the Server</param>
    public void LinkObjectToModel(IDevice device)
    {
        if (_objectModel == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("hv: objectModel is not initilized, try starting the server first.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Register Device: " + device.GetType().Name);
        _objectModel.RegisterAkomiDevice(device, 0, 4);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an internal model of the given entity and automatically creates nodes and callbacks
    /// </summary>
    public void LinkObjectToModel(object entity, string name, int curLvl, int maxLvl)
    {
        if (_objectModel == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("hv: objectModel is not initilized, try starting the server first.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Register Entity: " + name);
        _objectModel.RegisterEntity(entity, name, curLvl, maxLvl);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Universal-Automation support forum ?

Comment: @Kickaha Good idea! I've just postet my question at the [Unified Automation Forum](http://forum.unified-automation.com/topic1600.html)

Comment: Good luck with it. Would you post your solution when you find it?

Comment: @Kickaha yes, i will. But it seems like UA-Support always needs several days until an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a Solution. I had to add the following code to the "App.config" File. Hope it will solve your problem!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!--The UA Server needs this App.config!-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UaApplicationConfiguration" type="UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.ApplicationConfigurationSection,UnifiedAutomation.UaBase"/>
  </configSections>
  <UaApplicationConfiguration>

    <SecuredApplication xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/SecuredApplication.xsd" xmlns:ua="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd">

      <!-- Identify the Application -->
      <ApplicationName>My Server</ApplicationName>
      <ApplicationUri>urn:localhost:UnifiedAutomation:MyServer</ApplicationUri>
      <ApplicationType>Server_0</ApplicationType>

      <!-- Specify location of Certificates and Trust Lists -->
      <ApplicationCertificate>
        <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
        <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\unifiedautomation\UaSdkNet\pki\own</StorePath>
        <SubjectName>CN=GettingStartedServer/O=UnifiedAutomation/DC=localhost</SubjectName>
        <ValidationOptions>0</ValidationOptions>
      </ApplicationCertificate>
      <TrustedCertificateStore>
        <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
        <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\unifiedautomation\UaSdkNet\pki\trusted</StorePath>
        <ValidationOptions>0</ValidationOptions>
      </TrustedCertificateStore>
      <IssuerCertificateStore>
        <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
        <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\unifiedautomation\UaSdkNet\pki\issuers</StorePath>
        <ValidationOptions>0</ValidationOptions>
      </IssuerCertificateStore>
      <RejectedCertificatesStore>
        <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
        <StorePath>%CommonApplicationData%\unifiedautomation\UaSdkNet\pki\rejected</StorePath>
        <ValidationOptions>0</ValidationOptions>
      </RejectedCertificatesStore>

      <!-- Specify Endpoints the Server will use -->
      <BaseAddresses>
        <BaseAddress>opc.tcp://localhost:48030</BaseAddress>

        <!--
        Uncomment this line to enable the HTTPS based profiles.

        This profile works but is not officially supported in this version of the SDK.
        This is the HTTP based protocol that will be supported by embedded devices.

        Enabling this profile requires that you have a HTTPS certificate issued by a certificate authority
        in your root certificate store. You can create your own authority and add it to the root store or
        you can use authorities like VeriSign or Thawte.
        -->
        <!--
        <BaseAddress>https://localhost:48031/</BaseAddress>
         -->

        <!--
        Uncomment this line to enable the WS-Secure Conversation based profiles.

        This profile works but is not officially supported since it is not practical to support on embedded devices.
        You should not enable this protocol unless you have an application that must support XML Web Services.
        -->
        <!--
        <BaseAddress>http://localhost:48032/wssecurity/</BaseAddress>
        -->
      </BaseAddresses>

      <!-- Specify the SecurityProfiles the Server supports -->
      <SecurityProfiles>
        <SecurityProfile>
          <ProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256</ProfileUri>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </SecurityProfile>
        <SecurityProfile>
          <ProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic128Rsa15</ProfileUri>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </SecurityProfile>
        <SecurityProfile>
          <ProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None</ProfileUri>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </SecurityProfile>
      </SecurityProfiles>

      <!-- Specify Configuration for Different Components (Can include 'YourCompany' Configuration) -->
      <Extensions>

        <!-- Specify the Trace settings for the Application -->
        <Extension>
          <TraceSettings xmlns="http://unifiedautomation.com/schemas/2011/12/Application.xsd" MasterTraceEnabled="false" DefaultTraceLevel="Info">
            <TraceFile>%CommonApplicationData%\unifiedautomation\logs\GettingStartedServer.log.txt</TraceFile>
            <MaxEntriesPerLog>100000</MaxEntriesPerLog>
            <MaxLogFileBackups>3</MaxLogFileBackups>
            <FastTrace>false</FastTrace>
            <ModuleSettings>
              <ModuleTraceSettings ModuleName="UnifiedAutomation.Stack"/>
              <ModuleTraceSettings ModuleName="UnifiedAutomation.Server"/>
            </ModuleSettings>
          </TraceSettings>
        </Extension>

        <!-- Specify Settings when EXE is run with the /install argument -->
        <Extension>
          <InstallationSettings xmlns="http://unifiedautomation.com/schemas/2011/12/Application.xsd">
            <GenerateCertificateIfNone>true</GenerateCertificateIfNone>
            <DeleteCertificateOnUninstall>true</DeleteCertificateOnUninstall>
          </InstallationSettings>
        </Extension>

        <!-- Specify Settings for the ServerManager -->
        <Extension>
          <ServerSettings xmlns="http://unifiedautomation.com/schemas/2011/12/Application.xsd">
            <ProductName>UnifiedAutomation GettingStartedServer</ProductName>
            <DiscoveryRegistration>
              <Enabled>false</Enabled>
            </DiscoveryRegistration>
          </ServerSettings>
        </Extension>

        <Extension>
          <SessionSettings xmlns="http://unifiedautomation.com/schemas/2011/12/Application.xsd">
            <MaxSessionCount>100</MaxSessionCount>
          </SessionSettings>
        </Extension>

        <!-- Specify Settings for the SubscriptionManager -->
        <Extension>
          <SubscriptionSettings xmlns="http://unifiedautomation.com/schemas/2011/12/Application.xsd">
            <MaxSubscriptionCount>500</MaxSubscriptionCount>
          </SubscriptionSettings>
        </Extension>

      </Extensions>
    </SecuredApplication>
  </UaApplicationConfiguration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.SessionEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="SessionEndpoint.Behavior">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <!--
        Must turn on mexHttpsBinding instead of mexHttpBinding if only HTTPS endpoint configured.
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        -->
      </service>
    </services>

    <!-- Servers deployed in production environments should turn the httpGetEnabled and includeExceptionDetailInFaults options off -->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SessionEndpoint.Behavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!--
          Must turn on httpsGetEnabled instead of httpGetEnabled if only HTTPS endpoint configured.
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          -->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <!--
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
    </diagnostics>
    -->

  </system.serviceModel>

  <!--
  <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
              <listeners>
                  <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default"/>
                  <add name="ServiceModel Listener"/>
              </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
              <listeners>
                  <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default"/>
                  <add name="ServiceModel Listener"/>
              </listeners>
          </source>
      </sources>
      <sharedListeners>
          <add initializeData="VendorServer.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModel Listener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack"/>
      </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I wondered where this comes from, and found this official docs page (search for App.config on this page) https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdknet/3.1.1/html/L2ClientTutEmptyProject.html

So, it comes with SDK examples, and the actual version should be better taken from there, because it is very different from the one posted here.